# Why toFixed function in nodejs result difers between slightly different value of floating point?

Tags: javascript, node.js, floating-point, tofixed

I having a problem to rounded a decimal into two number behind comma using to fixed

i tried this.

```
console.log(24.675.toFixed(2))
console.log(31.675.toFixed(2))
```

It return (this is correct)

```
24.68
31.68
```

I tried to used

```
console.log(24.675.toFixed(2))
console.log(31.674.toFixed(2))
```

it return (still correct):

```
24.68
32.67
```

But when i tried

```
console.log(24.675.toFixed(2))
console.log(32.675.toFixed(2)) <- its 32 before comma instead 31 (first case)
```

It return (false):

```
24.68
32.67
```

Why is that ? i thought `32.675` will return `32.68`, but instead it return `32.67`

How do i make a correct rounded floating point like this ?

Comment: because floating point is odd ... 32.675*100 becomes 3267.4999999999995 - when you round that it's 3267, divide by 100, 32.67 ... I imagine these steps are basically what happens in `.toFixed` - the results seem to agree

Comment: @JaromandaX do you know how to fixed this floating point like this ? i have no clue about whats goinng on.

Comment: fix suggests it's broken, it's working within the limitations of how floating point works (this result is not limited to javascript)

Comment: Learned the hard way 12 years ago toFixed is no good. Just log and see the result for (0.105).toFixed(2) and you'll see. Just use Math.round, never use toFixed!

Comment: @MannyAlvarado how will `Math.round` help? `Math.round(32.675 * 100)/100`? try it

Comment: @JaromandaX lol you're right! According to ChatGTP there's a library that deals with this called decimal.js. I had a small convo with it, read about it! https://chat.openai.com/share/fd80df9a-196d-4dd0-9dd9-39844831a9a0

Comment: Nah, I've written my own fix in the meantime and it wasn't even my issue!! :p

Comment: btw @JaromandaX how could 32.675*100 becomes 3267.4999999999995 ? i tried my calculator and its return 32675. Which calculate platform did u used ?

Comment: nvm, i tried in my console browser and its indeed return .4999995 lmao

Comment: Yes, @Gagantous I was comparing apples to apples - i.e. I used javascript to demonstrate a javascript quirk (though, this particular quirk is a quirk of `IEEE 754 standard` floating point, which is used in many languages

Comment: `.toFixed` gets it wrong about 50% of the time when rounding off a `5` - this rings a bell for me, I know I've written something to handle this in another language in the past ...